# Modify req.body after file was saved by multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I can't figure out a simple thing. If I do pass files with the request, I want to save them, and then modify req.body a little bit inside the same multer middleware. My multer middleware:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, req.body._id + path.extname(file.originalname))
    },
})

const fileFilter = (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: multer.FileFilterCallback) => {
    if (
        file.mimetype === 'audio/wave' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
    )
        return cb(null, true)

    cb(null, false)
}
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 3, // up to 3 megabytes
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
})

export const saveFiles = upload.fields([
    { name: 'audio', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'image', maxCount: 1 },
])
```

Right now I do it in the router:

```js
if (req.files) {
        if ((req as any).files.audio)
            req.body.data.audio = (req as any).files.audio[0].path.replace('\\', '/')
        if ((req as any).files.image)
            req.body.data.image = (req as any).files.image[0].path.replace('\\', '/')
    }
```

Which is kinda annoying, I would like to just do it inside the multer somehow before it fires next(). I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `saveFiles` is your middleware function.  You don't show where you actually use it, but presumably you are registering it in your router as middleware somewhere.  Because it's middleware, that means it is a function that expects to be called with the arguments `(req, res, next)`.  You can replace that `next` argument with your own and do your work in their like this:

```
// multer's middlware function, we will wrap
const saveFilesMiddleware = upload.fields([
    { name: 'audio', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'image', maxCount: 1 },
]);

// wrap the multer middleware with our own
export const saveFiles = function(req, res, next) {
     saveFilesMiddleware(req, res, err => {
         if (err) {
             // upon error, just call the real next with the error
             next(err);
         } else {
             // when no error, do our housekeeping in req.body
             if (req.files) {
                if ((req as any).files.audio)
                     req.body.data.audio = (req as any).files.audio[0].path.replace('\\', '/');
                if ((req as any).files.image)
                     req.body.data.image = (req as any).files.image[0].path.replace('\\', '/');
             }
             next();
         }
     });        
};
```

Comment: Made a correction to the code - it wasn't calling `next()` after your `req.body` code.

Comment: Thank you. This exact idea came to me sometime later after posting this question. I guess I should have thought more before posting, but I really appreciate it.

Comment: @irondsd - For all the hooks that multer offers for customizing its functionality, it always surprised me that it doesn't offer a bulit-in hook for knowing when it's done.  I guess this is just the way you have to do it.